# groovy filter xml and print

Tags: xml, groovy, filter

I would like to read xml, filter for some specific 'category' and write the result to screen or to file as xml. I am not able to find the right type for XmlUtil.serialize or StreamingMarkupBuilder. Where can I find the XmlUtil.serialize or StreamingMarkupBuilder?

```
def input = '''
<shopping>
    <category type="groceries">
        <item>Chocolate</item>
        <item>Coffee</item>
    </category>
    <category type="supplies">
        <item>Paper</item>
        <item quantity="4">Pens</item>
    </category>
    <category type="present">
        <item when="Aug 10">Kathryn's Birthday</item>
    </category>
</shopping>
'''

def root = new XmlSlurper().parseText(input)

def groceries = root.shopping.findAll{ it.@type == 'groceries' }


// here I like to print the filtered result to file/screen
/**    <category type="groceries">
        <item>Chocolate</item>
        <item>Coffee</item>
    </category>
 **/
println serializeXml(root) // I would like to write here 'groceries' but the type is not something for XmlUtil.serialize or StreamingMarkupBuilder  


def String serializeXml(GPathResult xml){
    XmlUtil.serialize(new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind {
        mkp.yield xml
      } )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
import groovy.xml.*

def root = new XmlSlurper().parseText( input )

def groceries = root.children().findAll { it.@type == 'groceries' }

println XmlUtil.serialize( groceries )
```

To print:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><category type="groceries">
  <item>Chocolate</item>
  <item>Coffee</item>
</category>
```

Or you could do:

```
println new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind { mkp.yield groceries }
```

To print:

```
<category type='groceries'><item>Chocolate</item><item>Coffee</item></category>
```

Comment: Thank you. So the trick was to add children(). Than the result type is GPathResult.

Comment: Yeah, and if you want to search the whole tree for `type="groceries"` nodes, something like `root.'**'.findAll { it.@type == 'groceries' }`